# Spring boot: Using Rest template make post call

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate

I need to make a post call using following details using rest template:

I need to send json with 4/5 parameters, need to set headers for content type and accept, and method with be post.

Can you please help me with sample code to create the json object and set the headers and make the post call

Answer (score 1):

You can use postForObject method directly. You can give java object and for accept a response class.

```
SomeRequestObject obj1 = new SomeRequestObject();
SomeResponseObject response = restTemplate.postForObject("url-to-service", obj1, SomeResponseObject.class);
```

Comment: How can I add the headers?

Comment: If you just want to add content type and accept. They are not needed. Request and response bodies automatically turned to java objects already. If you want to add different headers you can use "exchange" methods of resttemplate.  In question you only mentioned content type and accept so I suggest postForObject ()